# While Starting AVD i am getting error

Tags: android

When i am trying to start my avd in eclipse.It is showing unfortunately launcher stopped.And i am not able to use the AVD i have deleted the AVD and created a new AVD still i am getting the same error.My AVD configuration is as below :
 [2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] Created AVD 'NewAVD' based on Android 4.0.3, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,

```
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Generic
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=no
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=160
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash=-1537072293
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=7in WSVGA (Tablet)
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.front=none
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=yes
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=16
[2013-07-04 14:15:49 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512
```

And the error i am getting in the log is

```
07-04 08:46:59.216: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d7 (res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_black_16.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.223: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d8 (res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_black_20.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.233: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804d9 (res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_black_48.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.253: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804da (res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_black_76.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.284: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e8 (res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_white_16.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.374: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 9% free 2163K/2371K, paused 3ms+4ms
07-04 08:46:59.384: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804e9 (res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_white_48.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.393: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10804ea (res/drawable-mdpi/spinner_white_76.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.404: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080096 (res/drawable-mdpi/toast_frame.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.414: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10805d0 (res/drawable-mdpi/toast_frame_holo.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.504: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 9% free 2224K/2435K, paused 31ms+5ms
07-04 08:46:59.543: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080106 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.543: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080105 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.563: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080104 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.563: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080103 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.573: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080102 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.583: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080101 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.594: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ff (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.623: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fe (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.713: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 7% free 2266K/2435K, paused 5ms+24ms
07-04 08:46:59.713: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fd (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.723: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fc (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.733: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fb (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.743: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800fa (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.753: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f6 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disable_focused.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.753: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f5 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on_disable.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.785: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f4 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_on.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.804: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f3 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.893: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 8% free 2313K/2499K, paused 3ms+4ms
07-04 08:46:59.893: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f2 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.903: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f1 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.913: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800f0 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.924: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ed (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.924: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ec (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.963: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800ea (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.963: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e9 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.973: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e8 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:46:59.983: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e7 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.073: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12K, 6% free 2357K/2499K, paused 4ms+6ms
07-04 08:47:00.073: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e6 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.083: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e5 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.083: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800e0 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disable_focused.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.093: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800df (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_off_disable.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.123: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800dd (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_check_label_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.143: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800dc (res/drawable/btn_check_holo_light.xml) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.153: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800db (res/drawable/btn_check_holo_dark.xml) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.163: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800d8 (res/drawable/btn_check.xml) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.253: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 7% free 2404K/2563K, paused 3ms+4ms
07-04 08:47:00.263: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080196 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.273: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080195 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.303: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080194 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.313: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080193 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.323: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080192 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.323: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080191 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.333: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108018f (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.343: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108018e (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.433: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 5% free 2445K/2563K, paused 3ms+3ms
07-04 08:47:00.433: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108018d (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.464: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108018c (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.483: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108018b (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.483: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108018a (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.493: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080189 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_on.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.503: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080188 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.513: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080187 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_pressed_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.523: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080186 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_pressed_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.603: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 6% free 2487K/2627K, paused 32ms+5ms
07-04 08:47:00.633: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080185 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.653: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080184 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.663: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080183 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.663: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080181 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.673: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080180 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.683: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108017f (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_disabled_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.683: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108017e (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_disabled_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.723: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108017d (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_disabled_focused_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.723: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108017c (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_off_disabled_focused_holo_dark.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.814: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12K, 6% free 2530K/2691K, paused 4ms+4ms
07-04 08:47:00.826: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108017a (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio_label_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.834: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080009 (res/drawable/btn_radio.xml) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.844: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080130 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_transparent_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.854: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108012e (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_selected.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.863: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108012d (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.894: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108012c (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_normal_disable_focused.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.904: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108012b (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_normal_disable.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.904: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108012a (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_small_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:00.915: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080129 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_selected.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.005: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 5% free 2572K/2691K, paused 3ms+6ms
07-04 08:47:01.013: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080128 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_pressed_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.013: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080127 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.023: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080125 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.033: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080124 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.063: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080123 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.083: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080121 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal_disable_focused.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.083: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080120 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal_disable.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.095: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011f (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.103: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011c (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.114: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011b (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.193: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12K, 6% free 2614K/2755K, paused 3ms+4ms
07-04 08:47:01.233: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080119 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_disabled_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.243: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080118 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.243: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080116 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_light.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.263: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080115 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.263: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011d (res/drawable/btn_default_holo_dark.xml) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.273: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108011e (res/drawable/btn_default_holo_light.xml) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.283: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080004 (res/drawable/btn_default.xml) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.313: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080005 (res/drawable/btn_default_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.333: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080135 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_dropdown_disabled.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.343: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080136 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_dropdown_disabled_focused.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.433: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 6% free 2667K/2819K, paused 4ms+5ms
07-04 08:47:01.443: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080137 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_dropdown_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.453: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080138 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_dropdown_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.485: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080139 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_dropdown_selected.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.583: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 4% free 2713K/2819K, paused 6ms+12ms
07-04 08:47:01.593: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c9 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_label_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.593: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108000b (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_off.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.613: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108000c (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_on.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.613: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c3 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_on_disable.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.653: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801bf (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_off_disable.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.665: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c5 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_on_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.673: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c1 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_off_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.683: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c6 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_on_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.683: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c2 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_off_selected.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.693: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c4 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_on_disable_focused.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.793: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 5% free 2755K/2883K, paused 5ms+6ms
07-04 08:47:01.823: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801c0 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_off_disable_focused.png) that varies with configuration!!
07-04 08:47:01.833: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d1 (res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_off_normal_holo_light.png) that varies with configuration!!
```

Comment: Your drawable resources doesn't meet the AVD requirements.

Comment: @Numair so how can i resolve this issue